# Google App Store Warning - You should upgrade to Apache Cordova 3.5.1 or higher as soon as possible

Tags: apache, cordova, google-play, cordova-3

I have received an Email from Google Play Store for my Android App:

> This is a notification that your com.mydomain.myapp, is built on a
>   version of Apache Cordova that contains security vulnerabilities. This
>   includes a high severity cross-application scripting (XAS)
>   vulnerability. Under certain circumstances, vulnerable apps could be
>   remotely exploited to steal sensitive information, such as user login
>   credentials. **You should upgrade to Apache Cordova 3.5.1 or higher as
>   soon as possible.** For more information about the vulnerabilities, and
>   for guidance on upgrading Apache Cordova, please see
>   http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html.
>   Please note, applications with vulnerabilities that expose users to
>   risk of compromise may be considered “dangerous products” and subject
>   to removal from Google Play. Regards, Google Play Team ©2014 Google
>   Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043

If I try the command mentioned on the given link/page, i.e.:

```
cordova platform add android@3.5.1 --usenpm
```

I get an error:

```
Platform android already added
```

How can I upgrade Cordova from 3.1 to 3.5.1? I have tried all sort of things like:

```
npm update -g cordova
```

But I do not appear to be getting successful. The version file in MyApp\platforms\android\cordova folder still shows following entry and no file in this folder changes:

```
// Coho updates this line:
var VERSION = "3.1.0";

console.log(VERSION);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some research, I think, I have found the solution here:

http://cordova.apache.org/index.html#download

```
npm install -g cordova
cd my_project
cordova platform update android
```

Running the last command does the trick and I get this response:

```
**cordova platform update android**
Deleting E:/PhoneGap/my_project/platforms/android/libs/cordova-3.1.0.jar
Android project is now at version 3.6.3
If you updated from a pre-3.2.0 version and use an IDE, we now require that you
import the "CordovaLib" library project.
```

Hope that helps.

Regards

Comment: when you updated the app, dit the warning disappeared from google play? I've updated my app to 3.6.3 and the warning is still there

Comment: I answer myself, after a few hours the warning disappears

Comment: Yes, the warning disappeared. Though it took some time, not sure how many hours.

Comment: Where can I get the CordovaLib?

Comment: I think u don;t need to get CordovaLib. It will be automatocally created when you will add Android Platform in your project

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Phonegap, you just need to update Phonegap to version 3.5.0

It's explained here:
http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/06/12/phonegap-3_5_release/

And here's the note from Phonegap that says how you're covered: http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/08/07/cordova-android-3_5_0-patched-with-security-fixes/