# How do you update a single platform?

Tags: android, cordova

I just received a mail from Google, telling me that there is a potential security flaw in our Cordova app. They point me to http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html

The article suggests to update the Android platform to version 3.5.1 and provides the command line:

```
cordova platform add android@3.5.1 --usenpm
```

Using that command results in:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.5.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.5.1
Platform android already added
```

However, if I *check* the installed version, I still see 3.5.1:

```
$ platforms/android/cordova/version
3.5.0
```

So, how do I actually update the platform?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148320/google-app-store-warning-you-should-upgrade-to-apache-cordova-3-5-1-or-higher

Comment: @CommonsWare: Hah, awesome. I'll review that. Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% certain the other one is a duplicate of yours, as I haven't played with Cordova in a couple of years. Assuming it is, let me know, and I can mark it formally as a duplicate.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Yes, it's a dupe. The answer from the other question worked perfectly.